# High memory usage of VS c++ program

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-management

I have developed a program in VS c++ which is about the solving of a large system of non-linear equations. I added a new solver to my program as a new header file but when I run it, it gradually uses all the memory (16 GB). Is there any way to find which part or which array is using this high memory?

Thanks,

Ali

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev that's for Linux (although some information still applies to Windows)

Comment: [Visual Studio 2015 Diagnostic Tools Memory Usage & C++ Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32786173/995714), [What tool can I use to analyze memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12167074/995714), [Memory profiling with Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19906588/995714), [Analyze CPU and Memory while Debugging](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/02/15/analyze-cpu-memory-while-debugging/), [Memory Usage Tool while debugging in Visual Studio 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2014/11/13/memory-usage-tool-while-debugging-in-visual-studio-2015/)

Comment: Abstain from raw pointers and `new`-expressions and such. Voila. Problem solved.